# A question on the Riemann-Lebesgue Leamma

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The following was extracted from Jeferry's Advanced Engineering Mathematics book.

[image]

The Fourier series is given in the following form:
$$f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx).$$

I'm curious to why (26) holds. Any help in understanding it is much appreciated.

Comment: If a  series $\sum c_n$ is convergent then $c_n \to 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, but the Fourier series have $a_n \cos nx $ and $b_n \sin nx$, not just $a_n$ and $b_n$

Comment: (26) holds because of (25).

Comment: @geetha290krm, that's what the text says too, I'm curious how

Comment: If $e_k$ is an orthonormal set, Bessel's inequality shows that $\sum_k |\langle e_k f \rangle |^2 \le \|f\|^2$.

Comment: When u shout, the high frequency component  of your voice in the physical space converges to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how: The author says in text that $2a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(a _r^2 + b_r^2)$ is convergent (which is a consequence of Bessel inequality).

Since $a_r ^2 \le a_r ^2 + b_r ^2$ for each $r\in \mathbb N$, we have by [Comparison test](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/09%3A_Sequences_and_Series/9.04%3A_Comparison_Tests) for series that $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} a_r ^2$ converges. By the [nth term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth-term_test), we have that $\lim_{r\to \infty} a_r ^2 = 0$. But this implies $\lim_{r\to \infty} a_r = 0$. You can repeat the same argument for $b_r$.

NOTE: I have presumed that $a_r, b_r \in \mathbb R$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$.